# How to conditionally remove columns in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to remove for each row, the column that has the "o" value.
For example: in row 3 delete the first and third columns and keep the second with the name as it is.

```
> stocks_grid2
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    o    o    o
2 Var1    o    o
3    o Var2    o
4 Var1 Var2    o
5    o    o Var3
6 Var1    o Var3
7    o Var2 Var3
8 Var1 Var2 Var3
```

**reproductible data**

```
n_s <- 3
l_s <- rep(list(0:1), n_s)
stocks_grid2 <- expand.grid(l_s)

stocks_grid2[-1] <- lapply(seq_along(stocks_grid2)[-1], function(x) ifelse(stocks_grid2[[x]] == 1, names(stocks_grid2)[x], stocks_grid2[[x]]))
stocks_grid2[1] <- lapply(seq_along(stocks_grid2)[1], function(x) ifelse(stocks_grid2[[x]] == 1, names(stocks_grid2)[x], stocks_grid2[[x]]))

stocks_grid2[-1] <- lapply(seq_along(stocks_grid2)[-1], function(x) ifelse(stocks_grid2[[x]] == 0, "o", stocks_grid2[[x]]))
stocks_grid2[1] <- lapply(seq_along(stocks_grid2)[1], function(x) ifelse(stocks_grid2[[x]] == 0, "o", stocks_grid2[[x]]))
```

the output would look like

```
  Var2
3 Var2
```

for each row

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Each row of a data.frame needs to have the same number of columns. I'm not clear on exactly what you are trying to do by deleting some columns in some rows. That doesn't seem possible.

Comment: i'm sorry, i am using a for loop to calculate data for each row so for each row: delete column, not exactly a data frame. just edited the question that shows desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall goal of the question is not clear but assuming you are applying some code in a loop you can try -

```
for(i in seq(nrow(stocks_grid2))) {
  row <- stocks_grid2[i, ]
  result <- row[row != 'o']
  #Use `result` for further processing if needed.
  print(result)
}

#character(0)
#[1] "Var1"
#[1] "Var2"
#[1] "Var1" "Var2"
#[1] "Var3"
#[1] "Var1" "Var3"
#[1] "Var2" "Var3"
#[1] "Var1" "Var2" "Var3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but is this what you want?

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  x[x!= "o"]
  
})
```

result:

```
[[1]]
named character(0)

[[2]]
  Var1 
"Var1" 

[[3]]
  Var2 
"Var2" 

[[4]]
  Var1   Var2 
"Var1" "Var2" 

[[5]]
  Var3 
"Var3" 

[[6]]
  Var1   Var3 
"Var1" "Var3" 

[[7]]
  Var2   Var3 
"Var2" "Var3" 

[[8]]
  Var1   Var2   Var3 
"Var1" "Var2" "Var3"
```